# grails ui dialog

Tags: user-interface, grails, dialog

I am trying to do something which I would've thought was very simple, but it's causing me a huge headache.  I am using Grails ui plugin to get a dialog box. I have a number of instances - some where dialog boxes need to appear when a button is clicked. This I have got working.  But I also need to have some that appear when the page is loaded... for information / warning purposes.  But I'm struggling with this.. What should I put as the trigger? I don't want the user to have to click anything before the dialog appears.

Also - has anyone successfully managed to change the style of the gui:dialog ? Mine was originally appearing as text with an invisible background before I added the class=yui-skin-sam to the main.gsp body, but that's had to replace the existing style class I already had on the body! how frustrating !!

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem... got it working by adding "visible=show" to the dialog's attributes. Example:

`<gui:dialog title="Modal Dialog" modal="true" visible="show">
  This message will appear in a modal dialog when the page loads.
</gui:dialog>`